# Programa com consumo de memória acima de 500MB por causa de muitas imagens

Tags: visual-basic-6, memória

Olá!
Procurei soluções para o meu problema aqui e em outros lugares e nada adiantou. Códigos e mais códigos para reduzir memória e nada...

Sou iniciante em programação e não reparem meus erros, estamos aqui para aprender :)
Meu problema é o seguinte:
Tenho uma aplicação em VB com listbox listando vários itens. Cada item selecionado carrega um determinado texto para alguns labels (para descrever o item) e carrega uma imagem para um picturebox (cada imagem é diferente)
São mais de 1000 imagens todas elas carregadas a partir de 2 DLLs.
No arquivo database.vb criei vários case. Cada item selecionado no listbox chama a imagem correspondente.
EX database.vb:

```
Case "Fulano"
                programa.idade.Text = "18" 'texto
                programa.picture.Image = dll.imgs.Fulano 'imagem
```

O que acontece é que quando compilo, clico em qualquer item do listbox o programa pára por 2 ou 3 segundos (carregando todas as imagens) e o uso de memória passa para mais de 500mb. Então o programa funciona normalmente porém com o uso gigantesco de memória...

Sei que poderia ter criado um banco de dados. Mas não sei como e nem sei se ajudaria
Qual seria a melhor solução para o meu caso?
Há como fazer com que ele carregue imagem por imagem?

Talvez criar um database só para imagens? 
Criar um despejo de memória no HD?

*PS: O ideal seria que o usuário não tivesse acesso as imagens fora do programa

Comment: O que provavelmente está ocorrendo é que ao carregar a DLL todas as suas 1000 imagens estão sendo carregadas em memória (por isso o longo tempo no primeiro acesso e o elevado consumo de memória). Seja qual for a sua solução, o ideal é você *não manter* todas as imagens em memória, e sim carregá-las conforme o usuário navegar na lista. Uma solução trivial (não necessariamente a melhor) é manter uma lista interna com os nomes das imagens e carregá-las dinamicamente de uma sub-pasta na pasta de instalação do seu executável.

Comment: Olá Luiz, obrigado pela resposta! Eu já tinha pensado nisso, porém não gostaria de deixar as imagens fora de algum banco ou dll.

Comment: O ideal seria que o usuário não tivesse acesso as imagens

Comment: Por nada. Mas não foi uma resposta, só um comentário. Como você mesmo complementou depois, o ideal seria que o usuário não tivesse acesso às imagens. Sugiro editar a sua pergunta pra deixar o problema mais sucinto e incluir esse "ideal". Facilita que você receba respostas mais completas/corretas. :)